# Smooth transition on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am using jQuery and SVG element to create nice animations on hover event:

HTML:

```
<div class="chart-picker">
  <svg id="user-radio" class="radio" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve" onclick="activeUserChart()">
    <circle id="center" fill="#F08541" cx="15" cy="15" r="5.733"/>
    <circle id="circle" fill="none" stroke="#F08541" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="15" cy="15" r="11.877"/>
  </svg>
  Active Users
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('svg.radio').each(function() {
  if (!($(this).attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1))
    $(this).find('#center').attr('fill', '#fff');
})

$('.chart-picker').hover(function() {
  if (!($(this).find('.radio').attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1))
    $(this).find('#center').attr('fill', '#F08641');
}, function() {
  if (!($(this).find('.radio').attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1))
    $(this).find('#center').attr('fill', '#fff');
})
```

It works fine however I'd like to add a transition here, having the inner circle fading in the outer one. What is the most elegant way to do it? Should I stick with jQuery or use d3.js?

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vDue/

Many thanks

Comment: Do you need SVG for this? You could get by a lot easier with some basic CSS like `border-radius`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need Javascript/jQuery for this, you could just use CSS `transition` with `hover`:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2vDue/2/***

*CSS*:

```
div.chart-picker #center {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
}
div.chart-picker:hover #center {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a fiddle with fade:http://jsfiddle.net/2vDue/1/

here's the js:

```
$('svg.radio').each(function() {
  if (!($(this).attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1))
    $(this).find('#center').hide();
})

$('.chart-picker').hover(function() {
  if (!($(this).find('.radio').attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1))
    $(this).find('#center').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  if (!($(this).find('.radio').attr('class').indexOf('active') > -1))
    $(this).find('#center').fadeOut();
})
```

edit: forget about that hidden css stuff - was going to hide/show the center element until i remembered fadeIn.